# Date and Time format issue in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2010

I have a MonthCalendar Control on my form. When you select the date it fills a textbox with the selected date. It appears in the textbox as the format that I want (Short Date).

When I add the new record to the database from my text box it loads in my DataGridView control as (Short Date and Time). I open the Access file and the record shows the correct format of Short Date. The data type in Access is selected as Date/Time with the format of Short Date.

Where is the time coming from and how do I get rid of it?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection        'THE CONNECTION OBJECT
    Dim dbProvider As String                    'HOLDS THE PROVIDER
    Dim dbSource As String                      'HOLDS THE DATA SOURCE
    Dim MyFolder As String                      'HOLDS THE DATABASE FOLDER
    Dim TheDatabase As String                   'HOLDS THE DATABASE NAME
    Dim FullDatabasePath As String              'HOLDS THE DATABASE PATH
    Dim ds As New DataSet                       'HOLDS THE DataSet OBJECT
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter            'HOLDS THE DataAdapter OBJECT
    Dim sql As String                           'HOLDS THE SQL STRING
    Dim a As Control
    Dim str_pipedate As String


    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.PV_TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PVdbDataSet.PV_Table)

        'SET UP THE PROVIDER
        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

        'SET THE DATABASE AND WHERE THE DATABASE IS
        TheDatabase = "/PVdb.accdb"
        MyFolder = "C:\Pipe Vault"
        FullDatabasePath = MyFolder & TheDatabase

        'SET THE DATA SOURCE
        dbSource = "Data Source = " & FullDatabasePath

        'SET THE CONNECTION STRING
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

        'OPEN THE DATABASE
        con.Open()

        'STORE THE SQL STRING AND CONNECTION OBJECT TO THE DATA_ADAPTER
        sql = "SELECT * FROM PV_table"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "PV_Table")


        'Close THE DATABASE  '
        con.Close()
        'MessageBox.Show("Database is now closed")
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseClick
        'LOADS TEXTBOXS WITH DATA FROM DATAGRID OBJECT
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        txtLocation.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
        txtProjectName.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
        txtPipeDate.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
        txtPipeNumber.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
        txtPipeSize.Text = DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value
        txtAproxFootage.Text = DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value
        txtInstallDate.Text = DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value
    End Sub

    Private Sub TxtPipeDate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPipeDate.Click
        'MonthCalendar1.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateSelected
        txtPipeDate.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart
        MonthCalendar1.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(1) = txtLocation.Text
        ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(2) = txtProjectName.Text
        ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(3) = txtPipeDate.Text
        ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(4) = txtPipeNumber.Text
        ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(5) = txtPipeSize.Text
        ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(6) = txtAproxFootage.Text
        ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(7) = txtInstallDate.Text
        da.Update(ds, "PV_table")

        'MessageBox.Show("Data updated")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click

        'ENABLES TEXT BOXES
        For Each a In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf a Is TextBox Then
                a.Enabled = True
            End If
        Next

        'CLEARS CONTENTS OF TEXT BOXES
        txtLocation.Clear()
        txtProjectName.Clear()
        txtPipeDate.Clear()
        txtPipeNumber.Clear()
        txtPipeSize.Clear()
        txtAproxFootage.Clear()
        txtInstallDate.Clear()

        'SETS STATES OF BUTTONS
        btnCommit.Enabled = True
        btnAddNew.Enabled = False
        btnUpdate.Enabled = False
        btnDelete.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    'Private Sub Clear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Clear.Click
    '   btnCommit.Enabled = False
    '  btnAddNew.Enabled = True
    ' btnUpdate.Enabled = True
    'btnDelete.Enabled = True
    'End Sub

    Private Sub btnCommit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCommit.Click


        Dim newRow As DataRow = ds.Tables("PV_Table").NewRow()
        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        cb.QuotePrefix = "["
        cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"

        newRow("Location") = txtLocation.Text
        newRow("Project Name") = txtProjectName.Text
        newRow("Pipe Date") = txtPipeDate.Text
        newRow("Pipe Number") = txtPipeNumber.text
        newRow("Pipe Size") = txtPipeSize.Text
        newRow("Aprox Footage") = txtAproxFootage.Text
        newRow("Install Date") = txtInstallDate.Text

        ds.Tables("PV_Table").Rows.Add(newRow)
        da.Update(ds, "PV_Table")
        Me.PV_TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PVdbDataSet.PV_Table)

        'SET UP THE PROVIDER
        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

        'SET THE DATABASE AND WHERE THE DATABASE IS
        TheDatabase = "/PVdb.accdb"
        MyFolder = "C:\Pipe Vault"
        FullDatabasePath = MyFolder & TheDatabase

        'SET THE DATA SOURCE
        dbSource = "Data Source = " & FullDatabasePath

        'SET THE CONNECTION STRING
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

        'OPEN THE DATABASE
        con.Open()

        'STORE THE SQL STRING AND CONNECTION OBJECT TO THE DATA_ADAPTER
        sql = "SELECT * FROM PV_table"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "PV_Table")

        'Close THE DATABASE  '
        con.Close()

        'ENABLES TEXT BOXES
        For Each a In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf a Is TextBox Then
                a.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next

        'CLEARS CONTENTS OF TEXT BOXES
        txtLocation.Clear()
        txtProjectName.Clear()
        txtPipeDate.Clear()
        txtPipeNumber.Clear()
        txtPipeSize.Clear()
        txtAproxFootage.Clear()
        txtInstallDate.Clear()

        'SETS STATES OF BUTTONS
        btnCommit.Enabled = False
        btnAddNew.Enabled = True
        btnUpdate.Enabled = False
        btnDelete.Enabled = False


    End Sub


    Private Sub txtPipeDate_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPipeDate.GotFocus
        MonthCalendar1.Visible = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: A `DateTime` type always has both parts, it also just a value and doesnt have an intrinsic format.  The Access IDE is using the format for displaying it to you.  The time should be 00:00:00 which means it did not save the time portion (if it is not, then it may be how the code you didnt show saves them).

Comment: Is there a way to display just the date in the datagridview?

Comment: Yes there is a way.  How depends on the mechanism you are using to display the data

Comment: I have added my code if this helps you help me.

Comment: See [MCVE] for next time.  It looks like you are converting the date to text by passing it thru a textbox.  When you pass it to be saved, convert it back to DateTime and just save `dtPipe.Date`, the time saved will be 00:00 set the DGV cell formatting to only show the date.  You have several leaks in that code too, by the way.

Comment: I'm extremely new at this. What do you mean by leaks?

Comment: any object which has a Dispose method needs to be Disposed of when you are done with it.  This includes all those Data Provider objects; they allocate resources which are not being released.  And you are not supposed to create one global connection.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is the time coming from [in the DataGridView]

Date/Time values in Access always have both a Date and Time component. The default formatting behaviour in Access itself is to suppress the time component if it is midnight, so a Date/Time *value* of `2015-09-28 00:00:00` will by default *display* as `2015-09-28` in Access.

> and how do I get rid of it?

.NET controls do not share that default formatting behaviour for Date/Time values, so you just need to set the formatting for the particular column(s) of the DataGridView to a date-only format like `d` for "short date". You could do that in the design view of the form ...

[image: CellStyle.png]

... or with code something like this

```vb
DataGridView1.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d";  ' short date
```

For other formatting codes, see

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)